# Reloading JavaScript engine without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing an application which gets script from server using ajax and execute it, I got success to execute that script. But my problem is I need to restart JavaScript engine to clear running JavaScript.

For Ex.

If I got this script from server.

```
var d = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log(new Date())
    }, 1000)
};
d();
```

And this script will print date for each second, now I want to load another script which print just time. How can I clear previous script from memory?
I tried by deleting variable d, but it is not working, and I cant use clearInterval() as there can be any script in ajax call.

In short, I want to reset JavaScript engine of browser to initial stage so I can load new scripts.

Comment: You can't do that without reloading the page.

Comment: what is your actual use case ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer, I am going to develop such UI application architecture in which we can load other JavaScript applications written using any frameworks, Currently I developed and when you change child application, it refreshes page, I want to avoid that page refresh.